# format specification for template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, format-specifiers

I have a C++ class that is templated on the integer type; something along the lines of

```
template<typename int_type>
void myClass(int_type a) {
// [...]
}
```

I would now like to read data from a file into variables of type `int_type` with `sscanf()`. For this, I have to specify the *format* of `int_type`. Up until now, I was doing something like

```
if(sizeof(int) == sizeof(int_type))
  sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &i, &j);
else if(sizeof(long long) == sizeof(int_type))
  sscanf(buffer, "%lld %lld", &i, &j);
else
  assert(false);
```

but this doesn't seem to be the best way to handle things.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's probably better to use the templated versions of the `operator<<()` bound to `std::istringstream` then, rather than `sscanf()`.

Comment: `sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned int)`, but `%d` is not the correct format specifier for an `unsigned int` (e.g. think about those numbers between `INT_MAX` and `UINT_MAX`). To provide different implementations for different types, *function overloading* is typically a good way.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a class  and specialization:

```
template <typename T> struct scanf_format;

template <> struct scanf_format<int>
{
    static constexpr const char* format = "%d";
    static constexpr const char* format2 = "%d %d";
};

template <> struct scanf_format<long long>
{
    static constexpr const char* format = "%lld";
    static constexpr const char* format2 = "%lld %lld";
};
```

And then use it like

```
template <typename T>
void my_scanf(const char* buffer, T&a, T&b)
{
    sscanf(buffer, scanf_format<T>::format2, &a, &b);
}
```

but a simpler method would be to use `operator >>`

```
template <typename T>
void my_scanf2(const char* buffer, T&a, T&b)
{
    std::stringstream ss(buffer);
    ss >> a >> b;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/zCqPO8)